# MVC4 Bundling kendo.common.css

Tags: bundling-and-minification, kendo-ui-mvc

I'm having problems bundling kendo.common.css in my web app.

After bundling and running in IE9, the styles are not applied and it appears to be breaking when it reaches @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active) and (-ms-high-contrast: none). This works fine prior to bundling.

How can I debug the bundling process to see if it is breaking when bundling this file.

Comment: I've checked the bundle in fiddler and all the css appears to be fine (checked in validator) but no clue why IE9 will not load the css

Comment: There's some thing in this file casing IE9 to misinterpret the bundled style sheets; it is ignoring some css rules that it interprets when not bundled. As a workaround I had to put the kendo css files into its own bundle. I would like to find out where IE9 discards css rules but there doesn't appear to be anything in the developer tools to see what has been ignored.